# Getting a daily forward OIS rate curve with QuantLib in Python

Tags: programming, quantlib, forward-rate, bootstrapping, interpolation

I am trying to build a **1-day EONIA forward curve** with QuantLib giving OIS yields from 1mo to 50yr as input.

My current approach consists on **(i)** obtaining the yield curve with `ql.PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount`; **(ii)** getting the forward rates with `yield_curve.forwardRate`; and **(iii)** interpolating the forward rates to get a daily curve (I'm using `scipy.interpolate` cubic for this).

However, I guess I might be doing something wrong, because I don't see the need to interpolate twice (first the `ql.PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount` for the yield curve and then the cubic interpolation of the forward rates). I think that there might be a way to get a **daily forward curve** instead of getting the forward rates at the tenors I provided in my input to then interpolate.

Does anyone know how to do something like this? I'm thinking that maybe getting daily data for the yield curve obtained from `ql.PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount` could work, but I don't know if it is possible to do that.

My code looks like this:

```
OIS_rate = [-0.474, -0.476, -0.4824, -0.486, -0.489, -0.4925, -0.5039, -0.514, -0.531, -0.5415, -0.548, -0.5375, -0.517, -0.4871, -0.4501, -0.4075, -0.363, -0.3156, -0.227, -0.12, -0.0353, -0.029, -0.052, -0.093, -0.1293]
terms = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 12, 18, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 20, 25, 30, 40, 50]

calendar = ql.TARGET()
bussiness_convention = ql.ModifiedFollowing
day_count = ql.Actual360()
settlement_days_EONIA = 2
EONIA = ql.OvernightIndex("EONIA", settlement_days_EONIA, ql.EURCurrency(), calendar, day_count)

# Deposit Helper
depo_facility = -0.50
depo_helper = [ql.DepositRateHelper(ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(depo_facility/100)), ql.Period(1,ql.Days), 1, calendar, ql.Unadjusted, False, day_count)]

# OIS Helper
OIS_helpers = []
for i in range(len(terms)):
    if i < 9:
        tenor = ql.Period(terms[i],ql.Months)
        rate = OIS_rate[i]
        OIS_helpers.append(ql.OISRateHelper(settlement_days_EONIA, tenor, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(rate/100)), EONIA))
    else:
        tenor = ql.Period(terms[i],ql.Years)
        rate = OIS_rate[i]
        OIS_helpers.append(ql.OISRateHelper(settlement_days_EONIA, tenor, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(rate/100)), EONIA))

rate_helpers = depo_helper + OIS_helpers

eonia_curve_c = ql.PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount(0, ql.TARGET(), rate_helpers, day_count)
#This doesn't give me a daily grid of rates, but only the rates at the tenors of my input

eonia_curve_c.enableExtrapolation()

rates_fwd = [eonia_curve_c.forwardRate(d, ql.TARGET().advance(d,1,ql.Days), day_count, ql.Simple).rate()*100 for d in eonia_curve_c.dates()]
rates_fwd

[-0.5013205348687322,
 -0.49759625549583575,
 -0.46846454432847295,
 -0.4893274862465269,
 -0.497305638893053,
 -0.49938936415339086,
 -0.5072289896701498,
 -0.5161230287393792,
 -0.5385846400502992,
 -0.5544383645075257,
 -0.5733276029449286,
 -0.5751842558616715,
 -0.5396298224269458,
 -0.47530380873128664,
 -0.39194197619440985,
 -0.28725299520226955,
 -0.17226686231897048,
 -0.06337764882502483,
 0.05217469101559402,
 0.15310894226860938,
 0.2696636782033579,
 0.3087449981915569,
 0.11321403246888906,
 -0.10714449333359966,
 -0.1991592137913223,
 -0.24303965144012452,
 -0.2836656308087271]

#This gives me only len(terms) forward rates, and I would like to get a daily grid.
```

After this, I do a cubic interpolation of the rates from `rates_fwd` , which I consider redundant since I already interpolated with the `ql.PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount`!!

Does anyone have an idea on how I can get around this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the first step, you are only fetching the forwards for the curve nodes. You could make a daily schedule and get forwards directly from the curve for each date.

```
all_days = ql.MakeSchedule(
    eonia_curve_c.referenceDate(),
    eonia_curve_c.maxDate(),
    ql.Period('1D')
)

rates_fwd = [
    eonia_curve_c.forwardRate(d, calendar.advance(d,1,ql.Days), day_count, ql.Simple).rate()*100
    for d in all_days
]
```